# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int' within an if statement

Tags: python, if-statement, typeerror

I'm trying to make a tic-tac-toe game. This code worked on Python 2, but doesn't on Python 3. I keep getting `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'` for line 18.

Here is the code:

```
gameList = []
for i in range(9):
    gameList.append(' ')

while True:
    while True:
        x = input('Which square? ')
        if(gameList[x-1] == ' '):
            gameList[x-1] = 'X'
            printgame()
            break

        else:
            print('Choose an unchosen square.')
            continue

    while True:
        y = random.randint(0,8)
        if(gameList[y] == ' '):
             gameList[y] = 'O'
             printgame()
             break
        else:
             print('Choose an unchosen square.')
             continue
```

Answer (score 2):

in Python 3 the input function returns a variable as a string even if it is an integer entered. Cast your variable x as an integer and this should work.

```
        x = int(input('Which square? '))
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here :  `x-1` (str - int: it's not allowed in python), `x` is an `str` (value returned by input method) you should cast the `x` to `int` first:

```py
      x = int(input('Which square? '))
```